# Why is Android Studio not creating the native-debug-symbols zip file when building a signed bundle

Tags: android

I have followed the instructions at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#native-crash-support to build the native-debug-symbols.zip file to upload to the Google Play Store with the new release of my app.  However, no zip file is being generated. Here is the code in my build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ndk {
                debugSymbolLevel 'SYMBOL_TABLE'
            }
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    ndkVersion "23.0.7599858"
```

I have checked that the ndk directory is loaded under the Sdk folder and it contains the folder for 23.0.7599858.  In Android Studio I select build->generate signed bundle. Under app/build/outputs there is no folder for native-debug-symbols. There are three folders named apk, logs and mapping. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same problem here since I upgraded gradle and its plugin to 7.0. Any solutions? https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/207626326

Comment: same with gradle plugin 7.2.2 when building signed APK. Any news?

Comment: I have not found any solution and have given up on Android apps.  Being limited to Android devices isn't worth all the effort.